# Utilising minimal MySQL queries when building a database-driven user system

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm building a user system for my site using PHP and MySQL as the datastore, I don't particularly want to run a MySQL query every time a user logs in so I'm thinking about using some sort of caching solution (such as memcache) to store user data.

My question is, is this a safe and practical practice to employ? and if not, how can I reduce MySQL queries as much as possible?

Comment: a decent server can handle 500+ queries per second while caching all data into ram. so I would not mind the request count, at least at the beginning. how every, before using memcache, check out the superiour redis.

Answer (score 0):

What is the amount of concurrent user that your site needs to handle? In my opinion the overhead for this kind of caching is redundant...

If u'r still go with the memcache, concerning security , remember that memcache is to your application just as the session object is to your application; It is considered secure as long as users does not have access to it.

Other ways of reducing MySQL overhead is setting all commonly-needed information in the session variable after login.

Comment: I'm designing it to be able to handle 100k concurrent users - when i'm done the site won't even be getting 0.1% of that but i'de like to build my site as essentially a framework that I can use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend, a lot depends on what type of system / framework you are using. I have been using Codeigniter for a long time now and one thing which I can tell you if that if you want to reduce the load on mysql then you can use the Codeigniter cache mechanism. You can store valuable information in flat files, memcache or even APC using the cache driver and this will reduce significant load on the application and mysql.

If you check my site http://www.amitavroy.com it's a site which uses the drupal CMS to add content because I have been doing that for more than 2 years and I converted the front end to a Codeigniter application. And all my pages are served as HTML pages. I have a cache mechanism  on top of almost every controller which checks if there is a cached HTML file available in the cache folder. If there is, then it won't even a single query and use the HTML file as output. And if doesn't find it, then it will run the required queries.

So when there is no cache, my home page runs around 86 queries - yes a heavy toll because Drupal spreads its information in a lot of tables. But once the page is cached, it doesn't run a single query.

This has proved to be a very useful method. In past I have worked on quite a few websites which had to deal with really heavy traffic and this mechanism does work. All it does is relies on IO and reads the HTML files. This is something even boost module does if you are aware of it.

If you need any more help, you can even contact me personally. Would be more than happy to help.
Cheers

Comment: On my site at the moment i'm using memcache to store page contents and then use file_get_contents to update it every now and again - it may seem pointless but for me at least it seems that using memcache is quicker than IO on my system.

Comment: Well memcache will sit on top of mysql and cache the queries. APC is an OPCode cache which will cache php files. You should check my the IO requests are slowing down your system. Because if you are only relying on Memcache then it won't be able to serve 100K users. It will utilize the ram which is allocated. But yes, if IO is used, a certain percentage of CPU usage will go up but not as much as RAM utilization.

Comment: The memcache server is hosted externally, so RAM utilization isn't that much of an issue whereas CPU usage is.